# How can I have a right-aligned span as part of the title of an Accordion element in Elementor?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, elementor

This is [what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e3kj.png) vs [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zm3q.png).
Basically, I want the time shown to be right-aligned while keeping the name of the event on the left. This is in the "title" part of an Elementor Accordion element.

**Normally** with HTML, I **would** add a span for the time and align that to the right, but **as I am doing this in Elementor, that is not possible**. I can't just add a bunch of spaces because then it wouldn't be aligned properly on different screen sizes. Is there any custom JavaScript or CSS that I could possibly use to achieve what I want?

Edit: As stated above, I cannot add a span. I am using Elementor. I am not directly editing the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with Accordion Tabs title sometimes is a mess, but do you know instead of adding just simple text on the titles you can include a shortcodes? This way you easily can do what you are looking for and also add more style on your tabs.
You can use images, colors, etc. Whatever you want! Just add the shortcode: [elementor-template id="XXX"] instead of your title text.

Comment: Wow, that's actually really cool. I'm going to try using this. Thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: I've tried using the shortcode feature, and I was wondering if you could help me to better understand specifically how I would use it in this situation? It seems like you can make a template and use the shortcode for that, but I can't edit the text in the inserted shortcode, so I would have to create a separate template for each specific heading with its own text (e.g. Breakfast Event 9:00-10:00). But I don't know much about this and might be misinterpreting how and where you're suggesting to use the shortcodes, so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that but one of them i would probably use is float.

```html
<span>
  Opening event
</span>
<span style="float: right;">
  11:00AM - 12:00PM
</span>
```

[More information about float styling .](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Comment: I specifically stated that I am using Elementor and thus cannot add a span. Elementor is drag-and-drop so I can't modify the html of the widgets.

Comment: Because i don't know WordPress, If there is no way for you to edit HTML code; sorry, i can't help you.

Comment: If the answer cannot be salvaged it should be deleted.

Comment: No , of course it can be solved , but not by me. We should wait

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **display:flex** property on the parent element of the span to achieve this:

```css
parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

moreover with css, you can also achieve this using **position:absolute** and much more.

Comment: I cannot add a span. I am using Elementor.